# Java process holding rolling appender log file

Tags: logging, log4j, locking, diskspace, rollingfileappender

I have an application running on jboss server and certain amount of memory is allotted to it. The application is lately running into high utilization issue and we can see the java process is holding a huge rolling appender file.

```
-bash-3.2$ /usr/sbin/lsof /ngs/app | grep -i delete java      22204 myapp  398w   REG 251,10 27235367937  528148 /ngs/app/myapp/RELEASE_QRTZ/logs/server.log.80 (deleted)
```

However below is the server.log.80 in the server:

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -lt server.log.80
-rw-r----- 1 myapp myapp 40000123 Nov 19 03:21 server.log.80
```

Also below is the rolling appender configuration:

```
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/> 
<rotate-size value="40000000"/> 
<max-backup-index value="80"/> 
<append value="true"/>
```

Can somebody suggest how do I identify why the process is holding this huge log file and how to resolve this?

Any help is really appreciated, thanks!